# Why is Garp only a Vice Admiral?

Tags: one-piece

It is clear that he is very powerful due to his fights with Gol. D Roger. He is also very experienced in fighting and has the confidence to defeat Admiral Akainu (magma).

So why hasn't he been promoted to Admiral? Did he deny the promotion when the option was given to him? Or was it because he lacked a Devil Fruit?

Note:  All of the Admirals has a Devil Fruit. Golden Buddha, Magma, Ice, Light.

Comment: Garp doesnt want to be an admiral because it will just add more responsibilities for him. Eichiro Oda even said that Garp is the strongest marine ever.

Comment: where have you read odachi describing garp as strongest marine ever?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

He refused to be promoted to Admiral several times.

In Chapter 0 (Strong World), he said that he had the freedom to do what he wants that he needed as a Vice Admiral (being the third highest rank in the Marines) and felt being promoted would just require him to do extra things that he had no interest in.

[image: Strong World]

Comment: Nice, not many know about Chapter 0. :):)

Comment: Well it is more common as chapter 565.5      . Anyone up to 565 will reach here at its end.

Answer (score 8):

Garp feels that the perks of being a Vice Admiral (mainly the high level of freedom) is worth more than being an Admiral, who are often used to guard the Tenryuubito (who I could imagine Garp would despise).

He's probably stronger than the current Admirals though. Remember in Marineford when Sengoku personally had to restrain him? That basically says he was scared of what Garp would do to Akainu.

Comment: Yes, assuming that Garp uses some Haki I guess Akainu would probably get flattened out.

Comment: It's been stated that all Vice Admirals have Haki (not sure if it's both Busoshoku and Kenbunshoku, or at minimum one of them), and based on his reaction (alluded to but not in certain terms that Luffy inherited Haoshoku by birth) to Luffy's Haoshoku, may have that too.

Answer (score 0):

Admirals work directly under the celestial dragons..since garp doesn't wants to serve them,he rejected the admiral offer so many times.